# javascript match method with a closing square bracket character

Tags: javascript, regex, match

How can I use a closing square bracket as a character in a javascript regular expression?

```
"Acb[".match('[\(, \), \[]')
```

returns:

```
["["]
```

But when I add the closing square bracket as a character it does not work :

```
"Acb[".match('[\(, \), \[, \]]')
null


"Acb]".match('[\(, \), \[, \]]')
null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Acb]".match(/[\(, \), \[, \]]/)` returns `["]"]`.  You should use `/` instead of a quotation mark to denote a regex to avoid problems with escaping

You also dont need to escape most of those characters. `"Acb]".match(/[()[, \]]/)` will match (, ), [, ], a comma, or a space

Info on character classes can be [found here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Answer (score 1):

[@wolffer-east's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081149/4556448) is correct.  I'm posting just to explain why his/her answer works.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), the argument to `String.prototype.match` can be a string rather than a regex:

> Parameters
>
> **regexp**
>
> A regular expression object. If a non-RegExp object obj is
>     passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new
>     RegExp(obj).

So it's not immediately obvious why using slashes to delimit the regex works, while using quotes doesn't.  The reason is that the two delimitation forms treat backslash-escaping differently.  When you write

```
"Acb[".match('[\(, \), \[, \]]')
```

The quotes apply the backslash-escaping first, before any regex is created.  Since backslash-parentheses and backslash-bracket are not special escape sequences, they translate to just parentheses and bracket, respectively.  Thus this:

```
'[\(, \), \[, \]]'
```

is equivalent to this:

```
'[(, ), [, ]]'
```

It's only after that that the `RegExp` constructor is invoked.  At this point the closing bracket is no longer escaped, and is treated as the ending marker for the character class rather than a character within the class.  You can avoid this by escaping the backslash itself:

```
"Acb[".match('[\(, \), \[, \\]]')
```

--

It also seems that you're using commas to separate the characters in your character class - this is unnecessary, no separator is required.  A simpler expression would thus be:

```
"Acb[".match(/[()[\]]/)
```

or

```
"Acb[".match('[()[\\]]')
```

Comment: Good call with the MDN reference, I forgot that you can use quotes but need to double escape.